# How to fill area between 2 polylines in WPF with condition

Tags: wpf, intersection, polyline

I am developing a charting application in which there are 2 polylines, say Polyline A (shown as red colour line in below image) and Polyline B (shown as blue colour line in below image).

[image: example]

There can be 2 conditions in the chart:

- When the red line intersects the blue line from above and then stays below the blue line, I want to fill that area with some color.
- When the red line intersects the blue line from below and then stays above the blue line, I want to fill that area with some other color.

Comment: Have you googled for "intersection of two polygons"?

Comment: Yes i Did but not found suitable in my problem

Answer (score 2):

Without ever having done this, i could imagine that you might be able to do what you want without much mathematics by filling a [Path](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms615632) and setting its [Clip](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.clip) in an appropriate way.

Let's say you fill the entire area below the red line with green. Therefore you would set up a filled `Path` whose `Data` geometry is a closed polygon consisting of all the points of the red line plus the two lower corner points of the viewport. On that `Path` you would set the `Clip` property to another closed polygon geometry, which would consist of all the points from the blue line plus the two upper points of the viewport. For the red fill you would do the same again, but with exchanged polylines.

The straightforward approach would of course be to find the intersection points, determine the direction of the intersection, create closed polygons from the upper and lower line points plus the appropriate intersection points and fill these polygons according to the intersection direction.

Good luck!

Comment: Can you give me little implementation of what you said in last para , i am also aware of this but not able to implement it , i know you may be very busy but please do it , if possible

Comment: Sorry i can't do that. Just google for how to get the intersection point of two line segments. Find the right segments by checking their y values. I assume the x values are identical in both polylines.

Comment: if these lines were straight lines then it would not have more than 2 minute task but real problem is nature of lines can not fixed

Comment: Don't your polylines consist of straight line segments, perhaps even with equidistant x values?

Comment: Then find the intersecting segments by checking the difference between the blue and red y values. If for a given x interval the difference changes its sign, you have found an intersection.